# c++ libconfig and lists

Tags: c++, list, libconfig

it seems I am unable to find any source telling me how to use lists with libconfig.

Let's say my config file looks like this:

```
Layer1 = {
    Layer2 = {
        SomeOption = "MyValue";
        Options =  (
            {
                Option = "Full Screen";
                Value = "No";
            },
            {
                Option = "Title";
                Value = "Test";
            }
        );
    };
};
```

How can I read Options with libconfig++ ? I can only find methods for reading single values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK, I have found the answer:

```
using namespace libconfig;

// ...

Config *pConfig = new Config();
// ...
Setting& settings = pConfig->lookup("Layer1.Layer2.Options");
const char* op0 = settings[0]["Option"];

// ...
```

Comment: Hi, I'm looking at a problem like yours and wonder about your solution.
To get the data from the list one is first to lookup the list into a settings and then parse out using name- value pair.
But what if I have a list like this Options = (1, 3, 6, 8, 0, 4,);
Does the same solution work only with "settings[0][2]" to index out the list data?
Is it the same solution for arrays?